# Using simplexml to parse curl response

Tags: php, curl, simplexml

I'm using simplexml to parse a curl response. I am correctly getting the response but having trouble getting certain attributes from the response...

```
//Sending my data to web service
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, Array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => 'https://webservice.tld',
    CURLOPT_POST           => count($xml->asXML()),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $xml->asXML(),
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => 'UTF-8'
));

//Get the response
$reply = curl_exec($curl);

$responseData = simplexml_load_string($reply);

//Print the response
print_r($responseData);
```

This then correctly shows the xml response as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<cXML payloadID="test" xml:lang="en" timestamp="2017-09-13T09:49:58.1219095+01:00">
  <Response>
    <Status code="500" text="Price does not match current pricelist" />
  </Response>
</cXML>
```

However, i'm then trying to get just the code and text attributes from the Status but it's not outputting anything;

```
echo $responseData->Response->Status['code'] .' - '. $responseData->Response->Status['text'];
```

I have also tried;

```
echo $responseData->cXML->Response->Status['code'] .' - '. $responseData->cXML->Response->Status['text'];
```

Wondering if anyone can help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
foreach($responseData->Response->Status->attributes() as $key => $val){
 echo $key .'='. $val;
}
```

That is what on php documentation which you can read it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)

Comment: I get an error with this Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object :/

Comment: did you include the the SimpleXMLElement class on your code ?

Comment: if not then you paste this on top of your page. (use  \SimpleXMLElement;) without the parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

The problem your getting (and this is why setting error messages for debugging) is...

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

$reply = <<< XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<cXML payloadID="test" xml:lang="en" timestamp="2017-09-13T09:49:58.1219095+01:00">
  <Response>
    <Status code="500" text="Price does not match current pricelist" />
  </Response>
</cXML>
XML;
$responseData = simplexml_load_string($reply);
```

gives...

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content in /home/nigel/workspace/PHPTest/TestSource/t1.php on line 15
```

If you change the utf-16 to utf-8, then this will parse OK and your original code should work.

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

$reply = <<< XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<cXML payloadID="test" xml:lang="en" timestamp="2017-09-13T09:49:58.1219095+01:00">
  <Response>
    <Status code="500" text="Price does not match current pricelist" />
  </Response>
</cXML>
XML;
$reply = preg_replace('/(<\?xml[^?]+?)utf-16/i', '$1utf-8', $reply);
$responseData = simplexml_load_string($reply);

//Print the response
echo $responseData->Response->Status['code'];
```

It would be ideal if whoever is generating the XML fixes this, but for now this will help solve the problem.